# Ant Automation of Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build-automation

I am trying to automate the build of a project, right now if I build using Ant it fails.

If I build with netbeans it is successful. (though sometimes I have to restart netbeans if I've made any changes like a svnrevert, or other things I've tried)

If I build with ant after the netbeans build it is successful.

Any pointers on how to troubleshoot this?

I've searched high and low for how to deal with this but have no idea. the build.xml and other build related files are autogenerated from netbeans as far as I can tell.

This is the error I am getting when I try building straight with Ant

```
C:\Users\...\nbproject\xml_binding_build.xml:6: typedef class com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask can
t be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

EDIT:
The result with debug enabled doesn't really give any additional info besides a stack trace

Comment: At least provide the error. What does it mean that build fails?

Comment: please run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 1):

"Netbeans projects uses nbproject/private directory to contain some system dependent attributes.Netbeans puts the JAXB path information in this directory, which cause my the compilation problem.

jaxws.endorsed.dir=D:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.7.1\java2\modules\ext\jaxws21\api:D:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.7.1\ide11\modules\ext\jaxb\api

This could be a bug of JAXB Wizard in Netbeans.

Solution:
Create another project in the current Netbeans environment and run JAXB Wizard once. Look at the nbproject/private/private.properties file, copy the corresponding line into your target JAXB application, clean and build the application."

Source: http://braveo.blogspot.ca/2009/11/netbeans-jaxb-problem-typedef-class.html

Comment: interestingly, there is no private.properties file unless I build in netbeans first.....I see it checked in for SVN on a few other projects in the same folder hierarchy, I suspect I need to add it to my repo. This might be my problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it looked like the private.properties (and private.xml) files were never checked in, so unless they had been built at least once by netbeans my build would continue to fail. I checked those files in and the build is successful now.

Comment: As a followup, private.properties contains hard coded paths, so while this did solve my problem, will it solve my problem permanently? possibly not. I need to investigate how to build my project without the private.properties file.